# Loading files with jQuery using webpack

Tags: jquery, webpack

I'm new to webpack so may be missing something incredibly obvious.

I have a file that I'd like to include in my `app.js` but none of the jQuery is working inside of it.

App.js is loaded at the end of the page:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
```

## First attempt

app.js

```
require('./bodyClick')
```

bodyClick.js

```
console.log('loaded bodyClick.js');

$("body").click(function(){
    console.log('body clicked');
});
```

#### Result

The console logs `loaded bodyClick.js` but beyond that none of the click event handlers are added.

~

## Second attempt

app.js

```
import { addClicks } from './bodyClick';
addClicks();
```

bodyClick.js

```
console.log('loaded bodyClick.js');

export function addClicks(){
    console.log('adding click events');
    $("body").click(function(){
        console.log('body clicked');
    });
}
```

#### Result

As above – the console logs `loaded bodyClick.js` and then `adding click events` but beyond that none of the click event handlers are added.

~

What am I doing wrong? There are no errors showing in the console at all.

I'm the first to admit I'm majorly lacking knowledge in the world of JavaScript module bundlers – as an extra if anyone has any good recommendations on books I'm all ears.

Comment: the question is about the webpack but there is no webpack config?

Comment: It is a laravel 5.3 install so I can't actually find the webpack.config... I've been hunting around for it

Comment: Debug the code: does the `$` symbol point to jQuery? Have you tried using explicitly `jQuery('body').click(...)`? Have you tried something akin to `import { jquery as $ } from 'jquery'`? (Please play with the syntax, I am not sure; jQuery defines the `jquery` module if it finds itself in an AMD environment, try importing it to override the `$` symbol, if it does not already point to jQuery.) You really should find the webpack config :)